# using OracleSessionStateStore with Oracle wallet in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, oracle, odac

We have a web application that uses Oracle DB (11g version) to store session state. This worked well without any issue. We moved to using Oracle 12c and we also use wallets for connecting to the DB. With this change, the session state does not work at all. I am assuming that this has to do with the configuration, given that wallets are involved here. the web.config file has the following entry.

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MyOracleSessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyOracleSessionStateStore" 
             type="Oracle.Web.SessionState.OracleSessionStateStore, 
             Oracle.Web" 
             connectionStringName="OracleConnectionString"/>
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Am i missing something here. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that this had to do with 11g version requiring the below supporting dlls to make it work.

```
oraclient11.dll
OraOps11w.dll
```

Also, Oracle.Web.dll is strongly referenced to Oracle.DataAccess.dll. So, make sure to check these versions. if this is not done, there would be issues related to the one mentioned below:

> Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess,
>   Version=4.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.